# Is there a way to export a selected color scheme into css for org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, themes, syntax-highlighting, colors, html

I know that you can set the `org-html-htmlize-output-type` variable to `'css` in order to make org-mode use a set of CSS classes for coloring output. However, all of the colors need to be defined by the user. Is there a way to make org-mode export a selected installed color scheme into CSS? I don't want to change my whole Emacs theme just for exporting HTML.